# How to print the query of .get queryset in django

Tags: python, django

How can I know the query when doing a .get queryset in django

I have this model:

```
class Artist(EsIndexable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

And I did this in the shell:

```
x = Artist.objects.get(name="Eminem")
print x.query
```

Then I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Artist' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from django.db import connection

x = Artist.objects.get(name="Eminem")
print connection.queries[-1]
```

Answer (score 18):

`.get` returns an instance, not a queryset.

To see the query that is done, do the same thing but with `.filter`, which does return a queryset:

```
queryset = Artist.objects.filter(name="Eminem")
print queryset.query
x = queryset.get()
```

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada: implying that this one isn't?

Comment: Actually, I really how to print out the queries, not just in .get and was wondering because it just causes errors

Comment: Other ideas may be to turn on query logging in Django, or use Django Debug Toolbar, which can show all the queries that were used with timing info.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take note of that, but for production log purposes,, I really need that simple connection.queries. Thanks for the suggestion!